# Why control characters appended after bash command?

Tags: linux, file, bash

I used the bash commands to append several lines to multiple configuration files:

```
> for filename in *.ovpn; do
> printf 'configurationscript-security 2\nup /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf\ndown /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf' >> $filename; 
> done
```

However the control character "^M" appeared at end of each line in the configuration file:
[image]

I opened the files in vim, the files before bash commands looked like as folows:
[image]

I am curious why "^M" appears at end of each line? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is Windows' [carriage return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%5EM), use `dos2unix` to convert file. Vim recognize the [file format](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/File_format) and displays it correctly.

Answer (score 3):

The `^M` can also be removed via a regular expression in `vim`, if `dos2unix` isn't available.

`:%s/^M//g`, which can be entered as:  <kbd>Esc</kbd>`:%s/`<kbd>ctrl+V</kbd><kbd>ctrl+M</kbd>`//g`

Not sure why this has occurred for you with just a simple printf command on a linux system, maybe have a look that you're picking up the correct version of printf.  I've given this a go on a linux system, and the local printf keeps the correct line-endings, as you would expect.